# Flasher Relay Wiring Diagram Help

Tags: relay

[image]

This is a diagram for a flashing relay. Normally used for automotive, I'm curious if I can get it to work with my needs.

I want to be able to start and continue the flasher with a 12V output, and while that output is on, flash a light bulb with a separate 12V supply.

Is that possible with this style relay?

Comment: Show a diagram of what you want to achieve. One point to note is some flasher relays won’t flash unless the load is correct while others flash correctly but the dash indication changes.

Comment: Posted and answered here : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/437966/152903